# Running gtk module from Python 2.6

Tags: python

I have python 2.4 running on my RHEL5 server. In order to get python 2.6 features, I installed Python 2.6 rpm and using it to run my Python scripts. Now I want to have some gui in my scripts and trying to use gtk for it. I do see pygobject2.x86_64 is installed and when i run import gtk from python command prompt (default is python 2.4) it works fine but when I run same command from Python 2.6 it can not find the module. How can I make sure python 2.6 checks the path for gtk and other default modules?

*** Update ***

I have used sample program to clarify my question.

```
#!/usr/bin/python26
import gtk

class MyWindow(gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")

        self.box = gtk.Box(spacing=6)
        self.add(self.box)

        self.button1 = gtk.Button(label="Hello")
        self.button1.connect("clicked", self.on_button1_clicked)
        self.box.pack_start(self.button1, True, True, 0)

        self.button2 = gtk.Button(label="Goodbye")
        self.button2.connect("clicked", self.on_button2_clicked)
        self.box.pack_start(self.button2, True, True, 0)

    def on_button1_clicked(self, widget):
        print "Hello"

    def on_button2_clicked(self, widget):
        print "Goodbye"

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

When I run this program from Python 2.6 I get following error :

```
python26 gtk_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gtk_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import gtk
ImportError: No module named gtk
```

When I run this program from Python 2.4 I get following error :

```
python gtk_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gtk_test.py", line 26, in ?
    win = MyWindow()
  File "gtk_test.py", line 7, in __init__
    gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")
TypeError: 'title' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

So with python 2.4 it is able to find gtk module and go ahead.

Comment: did you define the pygtk file with " #!/usr/bin/env python" with that for any version of python it should works

Comment: I did try " #!/usr/bin/env python" but I am getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should add couple of libraries like at the beginning of the file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class MyWindow(gtk.Window):

def __init__(self):
............
........
try this
```

Comment: I am getting following error by importing libraries.`python26 gtk_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gtk_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pygtk
ImportError: No module named pygtk`

Comment: install the library for pygtk first

Comment: Its already installed. `yum list pygtk*
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Installed Packages
pygtk2.x86_64                    2.10.1-12.el5        installed
pygtk2-codegen.x86_64            2.10.1-12.el5        installed
pygtk2-devel.i386                2.10.1-12.el5        installed
pygtk2-devel.x86_64              2.10.1-12.el5        installed
pygtk2-libglade.x86_64           2.10.1-12.el5        installed`

Comment: certainly it's install but now configured with python library itself , check the install and config from the link http://www.pygtk.org/downloads.html depend of your OS.

Comment: "PyGTK is included in most Linux distributions (including Debian, Fedora, Ubuntu, Opensuse, Gentoo, Mandrake, Redhat, SUSE...);". I don't know how can I include it in addtional python install.